# HttpClient append parameter object to GET request

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-httpclient

I'm quite the noob using Ionic  or Angular for that matter. So as a cheat sheet I'm using the ionic-super-starter template (link below).
I am trying to make a get request to my API and it works just find if I'm doing it like this:

```
this.api.get('user/'+this.user.userId+'/entries?include=stuff&access_token=TOKEN');
```

but when I put the url params into an object it stops working:

```
let options = {
  'include':'stuff',
  'access_token':'TOKEN'
}
this.api.get('user/'+this.user.userId+'/entries', options);
```

The only error I get is "Unauthorized Request" since the options object including the access token was not appended to the url.

In the ionic-super-starter template the `providers/api/api.ts` calls `.set()` for each key in my params object:

```
if (params) {
  reqOpts.params = new HttpParams();
  for (let k in params) {
    reqOpts.params.set(k, params[k]);
  }
}
```

but according to Angular University this is not possible since "HTTPParams is immutable".
If it really was wrong to do this, I don't believe it would be in the ionic template. Nor would I believe that I would be the first person to come across this issue.

However, I am stuck here so any help would be appreciated.

Link to Angular University:
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/#httprequestparameters

Link to ionic-super-starter:
https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/tree/master/ionic-angular/official/super

Comment: The search parameters should be *part* of the options, not the whole of it. You can add params, the immutability just means that doing so returns a new object, with the old and additional params set, rather than mutating the old one in-place.

Comment: Not sure if I'm mistaken here but: the API class as defined in src/providers/api/api.ts takes my params-object, creates a new HttpParams instance and appends each of my params to reqOpts.params. then it passes the entire reqOpts object to http.get(endpoint, reqOpts). So my initial params are only part of the passed reqOpts and not the whole of it. no?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out myself:

if I write (in my `src/providers/api/api.ts`)

```
reqOpts.params = reqOpts.params.append(k, params[k]);
```

instead of

```
reqOpts.params.set(k, params[k]);
```

it works.

if you are using a loopback API as I am you might have nested objects like:

```
let options = {
  "filter": {
    "order": "date DESC"
  },
  "access_token":this.user._accessToken
};
```

this won’t work. try instead:

```
let options = {
   "filter": '{"order":"date DESC"}',
   "access_token":this.user._accessToken
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I wasted almost 4 hours for this